# Bootstrap navbar positioning in css

Tags: css, navigation, twitter-bootstrap-3, alignment

Usually navbar elements such as the menu link are placed where you want them in your html file. But for certain reasons I need to do this in my css file.

Is there any way for example to change the alignment of my navbar-menu links from left to right? By the way: Margin-left: xx px; does not help here because it destroys the responive behaviour of bootstrap.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: try using padding instead of margin.

Comment: try class `pull-right`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `float: right;` property to your navbar-menu links I think it should work.

or USE 
`.pull-right` or `.pull-left` class of bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul class="navbar-nav pull-right">

</ul>
 <ul class="navbar-nav pull-left">

</ul>
```

Comment: sir; without adding `nav` class the menu won't appear.